# C# Change double click into two single clicks

Tags: c#, wndproc

I have been working on an addin with a treeview.
But a bug in the treeview control messes up double clicks because the next click get ignored.
What I want to achieve is a double click that is read as two single clicks.
I have found a solution to this where a double click is always read as a single click. Code Below:

```
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203)
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

This WndProc method is not my wheelhouse and will probably not be for a long time. But for this addin I need a quick solution. Can somebody provide an answer on how to achieve a double click to two single clicks?

Comment: Try: `m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. (0x0201).

Comment: Hi dr.null, do I need to add `m.Msg = 0x02001;` behind `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero`?

Comment: Replace: `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;` with: `m.Msg = 0x0201`.

Comment: I tried replacing `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;` with: `m.Msg = 0x0201` but it doesn't work. I even tried adding `m.Msg = 0x0202` (WM_LBUTTONUP) below WM_LBUTTOMDOWN but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I have found a solution. See code below:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x203) m.Msg = 0x201;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Treeview in windows forms has two events: Click and DoubleClick. You can make Doubleclick execute the Click event twice like this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.Click += TreeView1_Click;
        treeView1.DoubleClick += TreeView1_DoubleClick;
    }

    private void TreeView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView1_Click(sender, e);
        TreeView1_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void TreeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Click");
    }
```

Comment: Hi MightyElk, your solution works when the control is not a treeview. Because of the bug that ignores the click after a double click. It is important that a double click never gets registered. Anyway thanks for the quick reply.